# Структура БД MySQL (AI в двух таблицах)

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 одинаковые таблицы с разными названиями. В них есть поле id, которое является первичным, а так же автоматически устанавливается при добавлении записи (AI). Нужно сделать связь между этими таблицами, чтобы поля id не имели одинаковые значения в двух этих таблицах. 
К примеру, я добавляю запись в первую таблицу - id будет 11. Добавляю запись во вторую таблицу - id = 12.

Comment: осмелюсь предположить, что если *автоматически*, то никак

Comment: а глобальная (неозвученная) задача не состоит ли в том, чтобы получить впоследствии выборку из двух таблиц в той же последовательности, в какой строки добавлялись?

Comment: @alexander-barakin нет, главное, чтобы не совпадал id, так как он используется в другой таблице

Comment: тогда делайте не автоматический номер. и или в запросах выбирайте максимум+1 или, предположу, что можно сделать триггер

Comment: Иметь в базе две одинаковые таблицы — это ересь, согласно всем канонам проектирования. Объедините в одну, с дополнительным полем (например, 1 — данные относятся к первой таблице, 2 — ко второй). Если наличие таблиц с исходными названиями принципиально для остального кода, создайте соответствующие view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете сделать так.

1. Создаете дополнительное таблицу. только имеющий ID
2. Для обоих ваших таблиц пишете триггер который записывает в таблицу (1) и получает `Insert Id`
3. Записываете это значение как ID.

получится как эмуляция `Последовательност`и (`sequence`) в `Oracle` или `Postgres`